# Flutter error: 'wthrow' isn't a type. "wthrow noAppExists(name);"

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, gradle

i'm having this problem with `Flutter run` and i don't understand. I follow firebase's intruction to add a Flutter app:

1. prepare the workspace:
   install firebase CLI, flutter SDK and create a project.
2. activate flutterfire_cli and conigure a project `flutterfire configure --project=:<projectId>`
3. initialize Firebase. In `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Aditionaly, i change minSdkVersion to 21 in android/app/build.gradle. As https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=en states:

> If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, multidex is enabled by default and you don't need the multidex library.

The error is:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM M305M in debug mode...
: Error: 'wthrow' isn't a type.
    wthrow noAppExists(name);
    ^^^^^^
: Error: Expected ';' after this.
    wthrow noAppExists(name);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'FirebaseAppPlatform' doesn't allow null.

- 'FirebaseAppPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.5.3/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart').
  FirebaseAppPlatform app([String name = defaultFirebaseAppName]) {
                      ^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\sdk\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1153

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\sdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.9.0-1.0.pre.77, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.22000.1641], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.9.0-1.0.pre.77 on channel master at C:\sdk\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 80be2bfc9f (28 hours ago), 2023-03-07 12:20:06 -0500
    • Engine revision 4e6cbe0fc2
    • Dart version 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-300.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.22.2

[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\sdk\android
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\sdk\android
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\sdk\android
    • Java binary at: C:\sdk\java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32328.378
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM M305M (mobile) • 3200419b4b3536e7 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows          • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.22000.1641]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 110.0.5481.178
    • Edge (web)        • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 110.0.1587.63

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

- i don't like android studio.

Forgot something?

Comment: The code should just have 'throw' not 'wthrow'. Somehow your cache of 'firebase_core_platform_interface' has been edited/corrupted. Try redownloading it (`flutter pub get` or `flutter pub cache repair`)

Comment: It Works! Thank's so mutch.